# Skype on 17.04 not working

Tags: skype, 17.04

I just did the system upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04.   Everything went fine, but skype no longer works.  And by that I mean it seems like it's not connecting to the skype "server" or whatever.

I can login,  I see all my contacts, I can see my chat history.  And I can see people online  --  as they were before my upgrade.

People who I talked to on the phone and I KNOW are online show that they are not.   It also seems that I appear to not be online.

It's like Im not connected anymore.

I have removed and reinstalled.  But the exact same problems persists.

Anyone else having this problem or know how to fix it?

```
dpkg -l *skype* | grep ii

ii  skype          4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 amd64        client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service
ii  skype-bin:i386 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 i386         client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service - binary files
```

Comment: Do you see the normal Skype icon in your top panel? There's a patch available if you don't.

Comment: No,  it's not there when I run it.

Comment: What version of Skype? Is this a **recent** download from skype.com? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *skype* | grep ii` (not in the comments please)

Comment: Please make sure to start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: Are you able to make a Skype test call?

Comment: I installed (on Ubuntu 17.04) the old Skype client (the one you have installed) from Canonical Partner, and could successfully use it, so there seems not to be a general 17.04 problem.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson running Skype 4.x in 17.04, did you get the proper Skype top panel icon, or something else, or nothing?

Comment: @heynnema: Yes I did. Looked like and worked as it usually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different versions of Skype. Version 4.x and version 5.x. You can run with either/both at the same time. If you're going to want to run the 5.x version, you **must** get the latest download from skype.com before installing/reinstalling (5.1.0.1 is the latest at this time).

There are a few problems that need to be addressed, especially if you're running Ubuntu 17.04.

## 17.04 fix...

To restore the missing top panel icon, the fix is similar to the one applied to the Dropbox indicator. Simply run the application with "env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity". For example, to start Skype For Linux, you would use:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux (or skype for the 4.x version)
```

To make the fix permanent, copy the application desktop (*skype.desktop for the older 4.x version, and skypeforlinux.desktop for the newer 5.x version... and you may have both*) file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`, then edit the file and change the "Exec" line by inserting "env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity" (*without the quotes*) immediately after "Exec=".

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux (or skype for the 4.x version)
```

Some applications are set to start automatically and in that case, you'll have to edit the desktop file from `~/.config/autostart/` in the same way.

**General note**: that some applications overwrite any changes made to their autostart files, located in `~/.config/autostart/`. A way around this is to rename the autostart file, then in the application settings, set the application not to start on login. This way, the modified autostart file will be used (which has a different name and contains the workaround).

## Repository fix...

If you've had the original Skype 4.x version installed, and/or one of the Skype 5.x beta's installed, be forewarned that you **may** end up with duplicate repository files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` named:

- skype-stable.list
- skypeforlinux.list

and you'll probably need to delete the second one, or future software updates may error out...

In `terminal`...

Confirm that the first file exists...

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

if the first file exists, then delete the second file...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
```

Comment: Do you know if that `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` issue has been reported to the maintainers of Skype for Linux?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. It was a question to you. ;) (As I said in a comment above, I couldn't reproduce the 4.3 problem on my 17.04.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ah... do vs did... my bad. No, I don't know about either being reported. Dropbox has a somewhat similar fix.

Comment: I am using 17.04 64bit (Unity), and tried skypeforlinux 5.4.0.1 from official repo. There is no indicator, also not with the above workaround. Starting again via dash results in multiple instances. No way to get Skype back once it is closed.

Comment: @hako In `terminal` type `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux`. What happens? Does Skype start? Is there an icon in the top panel?

Comment: @heynnema: I tried your suggestion, and skypeforlinux comes up, including icon in top panel. I have changed the .desktop files in .config/autostart and .local/share/applications (taken out parameter %u and the part for exiting).  It now runs well, with a 4th process type=gpu-process which was not there before.

Comment: @hako please remember to vote for my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema: I rejoyced too early. After turning off and, after some time, on again, the autostart was executed, but the 4th process (gpu-process) did not start. So no indicator and no way to use Skype.  Tried to restart, also without autostart, to no avail, starting by commandline had the same effect: no gpu-process no indicator. Maybe, something else needs to start first, to prepare the system to accept the gpu process.

Comment: @hako It sounds like you may not have followed the instructions for the autostart file. Skype may have overwritten the mods you made to the .desktop files. Please reread my instructions, and follow them exactly.

Comment: I tried the following: installed Ghetto-Skype which also installs libindicator7 and libappindicator1, but did not run Ghetto-Skype. I started 'env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux', and it came up working, complete with icon in top panel. No gpu-process, though.

Comment: I don't know about Ghetto-Skype, or the gpu-process that you refer to. And the fact that `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux` works, tells me the same thing... your mods to the .desktop files are incorrect or incomplete. Please reread the procedure.

Comment: I did not do other changes to the .desktop files in .config/autostart and .local/share/applications, and they are unchanged (unchecked 'launch at login'). I also removed the skypeforlinux.desktop file in /usr/share/applications. I'll check after restart.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual version of skypeforlinux, 5.4.0.1, available in the official repos and on the Skype website, some extra modules, 'libindicator7' and 'libappindicator1', seem to be needed. After installation of these 2 modules Skype for Linux worked for me, including its icon in the top panel.

In my system (17.04 64bit Unity), an environment variable is set 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity:Unity7' which should make it unneccessary to add 'env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity' before the command. In fact, Skype starts correctly by typing only 'skypeforlinux' in the command line.